# button click event with get php page not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button, get

im using jquery get() method to get my PHP page into a "div".

heres the code i've tried so far -

```
$(function(){
  $('#rssRedirect').click( function(){
    var jqxhr = $.get( "event.php?within=100", function(response) {
      $('#page-right-event-result-wrapper').html(response);
    })
  })
})
```

what am i doing wrong with the button click event ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Syntax is off. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rssRedirect').click( function(){
        var jqxhr = $.get( "event.php?within=100", function(response) {
            $('#page-right-event-result-wrapper').html(response);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

heres the solution:

```
$(function(){
$('#rssRedirect').click( function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var jqxhr = $.get( "event.php?within=100", function(response) {
$('#page-right-event-result-wrapper').html(response);
})
})
})
```